# Log4J not printing messages

Tags: java, log4j

I've created a maven project and in that I've `Log4JTest.java` under `src\test\java`

`Log4JTest.java` contains following code -

```
public class Log4JTest {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4JTest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Started test execution");
        System.out.println("Hello! working with log4j :) ");
        log.info("Ended test execution");
    }
}
```

and `log4j.properties` is at root of the project and it is like -

```
# This sets the global logging level and specifies the appenders
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, theConsoleAppender

# settings for the console appender
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

but when I run java file, log4j logs are not printed. Please let me know what I"m doing wrong.

Comment: What have you done to verify your log4j.properties is really loaded by Log4j?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Could you please help me to do that? So that I'll check and get to know. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect your log4j.properties file is not loaded (as it was not included into classpath). Hard to say exactly without knowing your project configuration and how you run it. To start you can try to specify your log4j.properties file location as java arg -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.properties to see that it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I kept `log4j.properties` file under `src\test\resources` and changed following in `log4j.properties`

From:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, theConsoleAppender
```

to:

```
log4j.logger.org.test.practise=INFO, theConsoleAppender
```

changed `rootLogger` to `logger` and appended package name where my java file is residing.

This solved the problem! :)

Comment: I believe the content is not the problem.  The problem is (as you mentioned in the question)  "log4j.properties is at root of the project".  A normal Maven project does not include root of project directory in classpath, and I believe you are not passing the path of the config file to log4j properly